# W3C Throwing Error From Google API Script

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is probably incredibly simple. However, to recieve a high grade on my uni assignment i cant have any errors. Im clueless as to why this is throwing an error considering its taken straight from Google.

This is the error w3 is showing:

> Error: Bad value https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=
>   AIzaSyBu3MmlwvX4XDRXKNJcm1cyJRA9CtQHQy0&callback=initMap for attribute
>   src on element script: Illegal character in query: space is not
>   allowed.
>
> From line 115, column 1; to line 115, column 129

```
/footer>↩↩<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= AIzaSyBu3MmlwvX4XDRXKNJcm1cyJRA9CtQHQy0&callback=initMap"></scrip
```

Comment: What is that last line with the return characters?

Answer (score 1):

seems you have a space between  `key= AIzaSyBu3MmlwvX4XDRXKNJcm1cyJRA9CtQHQy0`

```
key= AIzaSyBu3MmlwvX4XDRXKNJcm1cyJRA9CtQHQy0
    ^here
```

try remove it

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu3MmlwvX4XDRXKNJcm1cyJRA9CtQHQy0&callback=initMap"></script>
```